# Show message "wrong user" in Wordpress login widget

Tags: wordpress, authentication, widget

I was searching unsuccessfully how to display "Wrong user" message in a custom widget that I find here:

[Login User into WordPress without Password](http://qnimate.com/login-user-into-wordpress-without-password/)

Here is the code, added in functions.php

```
<?php

class No_Password_Widget extends WP_Widget 
{
    public function __construct() {
        parent::__construct("no-password-widget", "No Password Login Form", array("description" => __("Displays a Login form which allows to login without password")));
        }

    public function widget($args, $instance) 
    {
        if(is_user_logged_in())
        {
            echo "You are logged in";
        }
        else
        {
            ?>
                <form method="get" action="<?php echo get_site_url() . '/wp-admin/admin-ajax.php'; ?>">
                    <input type="text" name="username" placeholder="Username" required>
                    <input type="text" name="action" value="login" style="display: none">
                    <input type="submit">
                </form>
            <?php
        }
    }
}

register_widget("No_Password_Widget");

function redirect_to_home()
{
    header("Location: " . get_site_url());
}

function login()
{
    if(isset($_GET["username"]))
    {
        //now login user 
        $user = get_user_by("login", $_GET["username"] );
        if($user != "FALSE")
        {
            wp_set_auth_cookie($user->ID);
        }
    }

    header("Location: " . $_SERVER["HTTP_REFERER"]);
    die();
}

add_action("wp_ajax_login", "redirect_to_home");
add_action("wp_ajax_nopriv_login", "login");
```

But there is no way to do that with this code.

The widget works perfectly, but there is not the wrong user message.

Please help me.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried that?

This is part from the link you provided, if this doesnt work I'll have a look into it more.

```
  if($user != "FALSE")
    {
        wp_set_auth_cookie($user->ID);
    }
    else
    {
        return null;
    }
    return $user;
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, Dean. I've tried, but only redirect me to h ttp://192.168.1.28:8888/scmFinal/wp-admin/admin-ajax.php?username=DarthVader&action=login, and appears only a "0" in the page. (DarthVader is a wrong username for test)